# Scrapy: Keyerror even when the items are clearly defined

Tags: python, scrapy, field, items, keyerror

This scraper is complete and should be in working order, however the items seem to be undefined and produce a keyerror when attempting to crawl. Its a very simple spider and only has 2 items.

[spider.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS20A.png)

[items.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3eVH.png)

[scrapy shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABgB.png)

I've looked at the way this is structured over and over but can't seem to find anything wrong with the code. The items seem to be clearly defined and the scraper runs but produces errors.

Any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thats not how you would set a variable in a class?

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of your code as it makes it much easier for others to help you if the code is embedded in your question, in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an empty BestbuyscraperItem class. If you see the code at  [scrapy repo](http://[https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1fd1702a11a56ecbe9851ba4f9d3c10797e262dd/scrapy/item.py#L48])  unless you pass the arguments the item class creates an empty dictionary. And setitem will throw key error when setting the value.

You should do something like this

```
title = extract title 
price = extract price 
item = BestbuyscraperItem(title=title , price=price )
```

See the [example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#creating-items)

Answer (score 0):

check whether the field was set or not, simply check for the field key in the item instance. You should probably check your xpath

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Scrapy for over 4 years and never felt using `Items` class

In your case, just do this

```
item = {}
item['title'] = SOMETHING_HERE
item['price'] = SOMETHING_HERE
yield item
```